# No overload matches this call when use Map together with function overloads

Tags: typescript

My goal is to use `Map` to make a mapping between the `activityType` and the specific `service.createXXXActivity` function called so that I can get the corresponding method according to the `activityType` and execute it.

```
type CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams = {
    cases: string[]
}
type CreateInsureActivityParams = {
    cases: string[]
}
type CreateRenewalActivityParams = {
    installmentCases: string[]
}
export async function createActivity(data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams): Promise<boolean>;
export async function createActivity(data: CreateInsureActivityParams): Promise<boolean>;
export async function createActivity(data: CreateRenewalActivityParams): Promise<boolean>;
export async function createActivity(data: any): Promise<boolean> {
    return true;
}
const service = {
    createTrafficGenerationActivity(data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    },
    createInsureActivity(data: CreateInsureActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    },
    createRenewalActivity(data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    }
}

enum ActivityType {
    UNKNOWN = '',
    TRAFFIC_GENERATION = '1',
    INSURE = '2',
    RENEWAL = '3'
}
const activityCreationStrategies = new Map([
    [ActivityType.INSURE, service.createInsureActivity],
    [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, service.createTrafficGenerationActivity],
    [ActivityType.RENEWAL, service.createRenewalActivity],
    [ActivityType.UNKNOWN, null],
])

function getStrategy(activityType: ActivityType) {
    const strategy = activityCreationStrategies.get(activityType);
    return (data: any) => {
        strategy && strategy(data)
    }
}
```

Got error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null]>): Map<ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<...>) | null>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([ActivityType.INSURE, (data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>] | [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, (data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) => Promise<...>] | [...] | [...])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<[ActivityType.INSURE, (data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>] | [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, (data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) => Promise<...>] | [...] | [...], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[ActivityType.INSURE, (data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>] | [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, (data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) => Promise<...>] | [...] | [...]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[ActivityType.INSURE, (data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>] | [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, (data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) => Promise<...>] | [...] | [...]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null]>'.
              Type '[ActivityType.INSURE, (data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>] | [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, (data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) => Promise<...>] | [...] | [...]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null]'.
                Type '[ActivityType.RENEWAL, (data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null]'.
                  Type at position 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.
                    Type '(data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type '(data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>'.
                      Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
                        Property 'installmentCases' is missing in type 'CreateInsureActivityParams' but required in type 'CreateRenewalActivityParams'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null])[] | null | undefined): Map<ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<...>) | null>', gave the following error.
    Type '(data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type '(data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>'.(2769)
input.tsx(8, 5): 'installmentCases' is declared here.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCAVOiBmmCWBjAcQgDsINgcB7YgQTwoDcdQAFRDAWwGcoBeKAN4AoKKKh5EXCFwBcULsDg5iAcwDaAXSEBfIaEiwEyCAEliXAK4I6jZiDace-YWPGTpchUtWade8NDwSCgASiQQAO6IADY2OEys7IjcfIIiYsoKMdEcJMAw7rLyisrqWroQAB5glHDAUJIgxHhQmBbNFNTiRihxCSAAFAAmyIhyQcboWLiE4eRUtPTxdg7JXACUcixwlBw4UgA8AEaUlNFIxAB8ANxCVTV1DVxNLW0dC93BEH12w6PjPVM5is3yW-VW3E2UG2u32EGOp3OiCut3utXqjWarXaSy6eEBP1Af2AY0MXzCpCisTBKySkK2Oz2hxOZwuNzu1XRTxe2PeeIJNKJIxJcmRIChMKZ8JZSKuaVcCGAVmIUEUFggt10eGoCnkZCYeGgznSonxXym2HwRFI82ohMGwtJExQFpm1rIyAW9ohG3lrjEiuVn2M9uJiHWt1c2gANCbgygzJZrIKHf8ycZEyDvXTfS5-aJA3AVWaQymwxG4zG4yXQuEqaHHQDyXWYtnHOs-fnC8WBbYhaMK1G-HdiBYOFB7agAp2oABVAByAGl5wB5ADq89SAHIt7HXKgQjQAGJHkwwAD6BAAovOr4fUCYV5v+FuAIy7uMmecAZVnISv24AEwfq4-63muNAADLbgAzFufjauYGIps6CzfooxgqDg0ipJSUAALKIGAAxqHGaiTgEAB0X6-v+0Z6nABoQJRNZAkmoJ9iAGh7mI5EplOkCUQex6nhe163vej7zvRUiMfgzGsa6VpzJ6doptxZEUYJYFXhBkEyfq8ksYCFKRK26k8aIfGcQJzELsu67SVAo7RNEGkaOsQhCG8uIqioEDAOh5AQCogyIPxARyFpEAdnmpo6vUXiYSAqThZxqHUEFmHYVwlH+cAAxpcsoC2YOAYBUGYaisQ4p8JcM6uElKChVAABkrXFMFoXlpWOhAA)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has structural type system. This means that both types `CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams` and `CreateInsureActivityParams` are 100% equal.

If you comment `[ActivityType.RENEWAL, service.createRenewalActivity]` line in `activityCreationStrategies` it will compile.

```js
type CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams = {
    cases: string[]
}
type CreateInsureActivityParams = {
    cases: string[]
}
type CreateRenewalActivityParams = {
    installmentCases: string[]
}

export async function createActivity(data: Union): Promise<boolean> {
    return true;
}

type Union =
    | CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams
    | CreateInsureActivityParams
    | CreateRenewalActivityParams

const service = {
    createTrafficGenerationActivity(data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    },
    createInsureActivity(data: CreateInsureActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    },
    createRenewalActivity(data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    }
}

enum ActivityType {
    UNKNOWN = '',
    TRAFFIC_GENERATION = '1',
    INSURE = '2',
    RENEWAL = '3'
}

// COMPILES
const activityCreationStrategies = new Map([
    [ActivityType.INSURE, service.createInsureActivity],
    [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, service.createTrafficGenerationActivity],
    // [ActivityType.RENEWAL, service.createRenewalActivity],
    [ActivityType.UNKNOWN, null],
])
```

Also, there is no need to overload this function `createActivity`.
Above code compiles because of Map built ins type `lib.es2015.collection.d.ts`.

```js
interface MapConstructor {
    new<K, V>(entries?: readonly (readonly [K, V])[] | null): Map<K, V>;
}
```

`K` and `V` generics infered as `Map<ActivityType, ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | null>`

As you see, `V` generic infered as `((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>)`.

This is because `async function createActivity(data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams): Promise<boolean>` and `async function createActivity(data: CreateInsureActivityParams): Promise<boolean>` are equal.

While `async function createActivity(data: CreateRenewalActivityParams): Promise<boolean>` is not assignable to any of them.

Consider this example:

```js
declare var fn1: (data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>
declare var fn2: (data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>

fn1 = fn2 // error
fn2 = fn1 // error
```

One thing you can do - is to overload your `Map`:

```js
type CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams = {
    cases: string[]
}
type CreateInsureActivityParams = {
    cases: string[]
}
type CreateRenewalActivityParams = {
    installmentCases: string[]
}

export async function createActivity(data: Union): Promise<boolean> {
    return true;
}

type Union =
    | CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams
    | CreateInsureActivityParams
    | CreateRenewalActivityParams

const service = {
    createTrafficGenerationActivity(data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    },
    createInsureActivity(data: CreateInsureActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    },
    createRenewalActivity(data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) {
        return createActivity(data);
    }
}

enum ActivityType {
    UNKNOWN = '',
    TRAFFIC_GENERATION = '1',
    INSURE = '2',
    RENEWAL = '3'
}

type All =
    & Map<ActivityType.INSURE, (data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>>
    & Map<ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, (data: CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>>
    & Map<ActivityType.RENEWAL, (data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>>
    & Map<ActivityType.UNKNOWN, null>


// compiles
const result: All = new Map<any, any>([
    [ActivityType.INSURE, service.createInsureActivity],
    [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, service.createTrafficGenerationActivity],
    [ActivityType.RENEWAL, service.createRenewalActivity],
    [ActivityType.UNKNOWN, null],
])

// ((data: CreateInsureActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | undefined
const insure = result.get(ActivityType.INSURE)

// ((data:CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | undefined
const generation = result.get(ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION)

// ((data: CreateRenewalActivityParams) => Promise<boolean>) | undefined
const renewal = result.get(ActivityType.RENEWAL)

// null | undefined
const unknown = result.get(ActivityType.UNKNOWN)
```

Drawback: you have to use `Map<any, any>`.

Or, you can refactor your `service` object.

```js
type CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams = {
    cases: string[]
}
type CreateInsureActivityParams = {
    cases: string[]
}
type CreateRenewalActivityParams = {
    installmentCases: string[]
}

export async function createActivity(data: Union): Promise<boolean> {
    return true;
}

type Union =
    | CreateTrafficGenerationActivityParams
    | CreateInsureActivityParams
    | CreateRenewalActivityParams

const service = {
    go(data: Union) {
        // your implementation
        return createActivity(data);
    }
}

enum ActivityType {
    UNKNOWN = '',
    TRAFFIC_GENERATION = '1',
    INSURE = '2',
    RENEWAL = '3'
}

const result = new Map([
    [ActivityType.INSURE, service.go],
    [ActivityType.TRAFFIC_GENERATION, service.go],
    [ActivityType.RENEWAL, service.go],
    [ActivityType.UNKNOWN, null],
])

const x = result.get(ActivityType.RENEWAL)()
```

Since return type of each service is the same, you can move strategy logic inside `go` method.